# i want to hide or show div on mouse over of button

Tags: css

there are 2 div the data on that div i fetch records from database on "details" button over i want to display those div javascript is not working there when i apply java script it shows only first id i submit the code which i used in that please give me soluation 
[image: i want to display the blue colors div when mouse is over on details button javascript onmouse over and mouse out are not working it shows only 1 record on both div]

```
 <?php

    $sml_add="SELECT * FROM small_add WHERE sub_dest='$sub_desti_id' AND active_hotel='YES' ";
    $sml_add1=mysql_query($sml_add);
    while($sml_add_res=mysql_fetch_assoc($sml_add1))
    {   

            ?>


          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
          <div class="small-add" style="height:263px;" >
            <div class="result-box-heading">
        <?php echo $sml_add_res["hotel_keyword"]; ?>
         </div> <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <center><img src="./../smalladd_picture/<?php echo $sml_add_res["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive"  style="width:130px;height:84px;padding:5px;"></center>
            <div class="small-add-inner">
            <h2 style="padding:-25px;"><?php echo $sml_add_res["hotel_name"]; ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $sml_add_res["location"]; ?></p>
            <p style="color:#c90017;"><?php echo $sml_add_res["cost"]; ?></p>
            <div class="small-add-but"  style="width:95px;position:relative;top:16px;right:20px;"><a id="detail" style="border:1px solid #88D9FF;" >Details</a></div>
            <div class="small-add-but"style="position:relative;right:-35px;top:-14px;" ><a  style="border:1px solid #88D9FF;"href="hotel-details.php">Contact</a></div> 
        </div>

          </div>

        <style>
          hr {

          border-top:1px dotted #88D9FF;
          color:#fff;
          background-color:#fff;
          height:-10px;
          width:100%;
          position:relative;
          top:-25px;
        }
        </style>

        <style>
        #div1{

        border:1px solid white;
        height:260px;
        width:500px;
        position:absolute;
        top:10px;
        right:190px;
        background:#1A8CFF;
        border-radius:5px;
        text-color:white;
        }
        </style>
        <div id="div1" >
        <img src="./../smalladd_picture/<?php echo $sml_add_res["image"]; ?>" height="80px" width="90px" style="margin:20px;">
        <div style="position:absolute; top:15px; left:122px;">
        <p style="color:white;"><?php echo $sml_add_res["hotel_keyword"]; ?></p>
        <p style="color:white;"><?php echo $sml_add_res["hotel_name"]; ?></p>
        <p style="color:white;"><?php echo $sml_add_res["location"]; ?></p>
        <p style="color:white;"><?php echo $sml_add_res["cost"]; ?></p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div style="position:relative;left:20px;top:-25px;">
        <p style="color:white;">CUISINES:   Biryani, North Indian, Mughlai, Chinese, Seafood</p>
        <p style="color:white;">COST FOR TWO:   Rs. 800</p>
        <p style="color:white;">HOURS:  9 AM to 12 Midnight</p>
        <p style="color:white;">FEATURED IN:Trending this Week</p>
        </div>
        </div>
         </div>  


      <?php

    }  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be able to use CSS to display

Add this to your css file for #details:

```
#details:hover #div1{
display:block
}
```

Add this to your css inside the div1:

```
#div1{
display:none
}
```

It should display #div1 when the mouse is over #details.

Btw, please next time improve your english. it's really difficult to understand what you are saying.

Edit for improvement:

Sorry, for the above code to work, div1 should be a child of details, my fault.

Anyway, you can achieve a solution with javascript with:

```
onmouseout="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none'" 
onmouseover="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'display'"
```

to your tag with id details as:

```
<a id='details' onmouseout="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none'" onmouseover="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'display'" .... >....</a>
```

Comment: I edited the solution I explained why the older didn't not worked. You should use javascript or change your html tree to put div1 as child of details. I recommend you the first option.

Comment: sir its showing div but on both detail buttons it shows detail information about 1st record . in 2nd div the detail information is different which i fetch from database .

Comment: Sir, if you want to use it for create several divs with the same function, then create it dynamically, and change the id for the one you want to show/hide. Example: id=details1 hide/show id=div1
                id=details2 hide/show id=div2   
                id=details3 hide/show id=div3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger an event in CSS you have to use pseudo classes in this case :hover. so set the visibility of your element to hidden and then set it back to visible on hover.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to hide the div block on mouse over of the button via CSS is to make use of :hover event with pseudo classes.

The example for same is as mentioned below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hide div on mouse hover of button</title>
<style>
div {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
button:hover ~ div {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button>button</button>
    <div>This is div block</div>
</body>
</html>
```